# Message drops in PubSub

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I was sending messages to pubsub from a cloud functions and receiving them in Java from a global window using PubsubIO. Sometimes few of the messages that were passed from the Cloud Function do not appear when pulled from Java (In my case 4 out of 200 were missed).

My Cloud Function:

```
const PubSub = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');
const pubsub = PubSub();

exports.messagePublisher= function(event,callback) {
  const file = event.data;

  function publishMessage(){
    console.log('Publishing message to Scheduler: '+file.name);
    //Get Topic
    const topic = pubsub.topic('projects/analytics-and-presentation/topics/newTestTopic');

    var publisher = topic.publisher();

    var message = "sampleText";

    // Publishes a message
    publisher.publish(new Buffer.from(message), (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error occurred',err); publishMessge();
      } else {
        console.log('Message published');
      }
    });
  }

  if (file.resourceState === 'exists' && file.name) {
    publishMessage();
  }
  callback();
};
```

What should I do to make sure that none of the messages get dropped?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the messages are getting dropped because they were declared late data. See the Windowing and Triggering section in the programming guide, particularly [Watermarks and late data](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#watermarks-and-late-data), [Handling late data](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#handling-late-data) and the [Default trigger](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#the-default-trigger) *(I strongly recommend to read those sections completely beginning to end, rather than just the sub-sections I linked)*

You can configure your windowing/triggering strategy to either be more permissive as to what counts as late data, or to not drop the late data at all.

You may also need to configure the way that your PubsubIO assigns event-time timestamps. See [javadoc](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubIO.Read.html#withTimestampAttribute-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Came back to this after long time... @jkff, with context in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49626343/in-dataflow-with-pubsubio-is-there-any-possibility-of-late-data-in-a-global-wind my query was if we are using global window the data should arrive late... But not get dropped...