# In Dataflow with PubsubIO is there any possibility of late data in a global window?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I was going to start developing programs in Google cloud Pubsub. Just wanted to confirm this once.

From the beam documentation the data loss can only occur if data was declared late by Pubsub. Is it safe to assume that the data will always be delivered without any message drops (Late data) when using a global window?

From the concepts of watermark and lateness I have come to a conclusion that these metrics are critical in conditions where custom windowing is applied over the data being received with event based triggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're working with streaming data, choosing a global window basically means that you are going to completely ignore event time. Instead, you will be taking snapshots of your data in processing time (that is, as they arrive) using triggers. Therefore, you can no longer define data as "late" (neither "early" or "on time" for that matter).

You should choose this approach if you are not interested in the time at which these events actually happened but, instead, you just want to group them according to the order in which they were observed. I would suggest that you go through [this](https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/the-world-beyond-batch-streaming-102) great article on streaming data processing, especially the part under *When/Where: Processing-time windows* which includes some nice visuals comparing different windowing strategies.